# R won't delete all rows in command (but no error)

Tags: r, rows, delete-row

I'm very new to this and I know that I am probably making a variety of mistakes with this post alone, so apologies in advance. (I have tried to search for similar problems, couldn't find much).

I have a df with about 15k rows and want to delete a select few

`df <- df[-c(7422, 9024, 9198, 10024, 10139, 10402, 11481, 14025), ]`

For some reason, the last two won't go, even when try to remove them manually.

```
df <- df[-c(11481), ] 
df <- df[-c(14025), ]
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: What are `df`'s columns?  Can you show us with `head(df)` ?

Comment: Do those rows exist? What is `df[11481, ]` prior to deleting any of the rows? If you delete *one* row and then try to delete row `11481`, it might now be row `11480`.

Comment: @DavidT 23 columns, they're different kinds of performance data for a social media network. (Id, text, multiple interactions count, date (split into date/time/ time of the day). 

I won't name them all (won't fit) but here's a sense:

1] "id"                             
 [2] "date"                           
 [3] "type"                           
 [4] "headline"                          
 [5] "description"                        
 [6] "subscribers"                                                    
 [7] "description"                    
[8] "statistics"

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yes, I can see them when I view the df and when I input the command for it, like you have suggested.

Comment: Also, thank you both already for your help!

Comment: @RuiBarradas You're right. I re-did all of it and deleted in bulk and it worked. Thank you both again!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to be sure without a clearer sample.  But Try

```
df <- subset(df, ! id %in% c(11481, 14025))
```

Comment: Thank you David! @RuiBarradas had already pointed me in the right direction but I will keep this for the future. I will also try to answer my own question.